# Why does optocoupler 6N137 have a negative enable current?

Tags: opto-isolator

I don't understand how can I enable/disable the [6N137](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84732/6n137.pdf) optocoupler, because in the datasheet a negative current is shown. Is that a mistake in the sheet?

It states that the low/high voltages are positive: 0..0.8 and 2..VCC respectively, but the high/low enable current is negative.

Just to state that I blew up one charger the last time I was trying to enable it with the pin (with a resistor of 10 kΩ connected to VCC, just for experimenting). I know that it's enabled by default and that connecting it to GND will disable it. Also, it seems to consume less power when its explicitly enabled, so at least for that it was worth it.

I can't be sure that this was the cause of the blast, but the optocoupler stopped working after that (only the output side where the enable/disable pin is; the input LED still conducts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the measurements are not done when enable pin is set to VCC, but voltages below VCC.

If you pull the pin down to 0.5V, up to 1.6mA flows out from the pin.

If you pull the pin up to 2.0V, still up to 1.6mA flows out from the pin.

It simply means that there is internal biasing or pull-up circuitry that pulls the enable pin high, to keep it enabled with no external connections, and externally it is needed to pull current out of the pin to bring the voltage down.

Comment: I understand the words, but I do not understand how to use this exactly. Can you please give an example with a simple resistor how to make the pin low and high?

Comment: Does "pull current out" means to connect to GND with a resistor like 10 kOhm, to basically dissipate the current as heat? And I must **not** connect it to VCC, because it shorts right?

Comment: No, it means none of that. It means if you short enable pin to GND, there is 0V and chip outputs up to 1.6mA. It also means you can't connect 10k to ground, because it is too weak to pull it low. It means you must put a strong enough resistance like 500 ohms or less, to make sure that the pin voltage is at most 0.8V when 1.6mA flows out of it. You can freely connect VCC to enable.

Comment: I do not understand that at all. Is this "enable pin" an input or an output pin? Its ratings are into the input section of the ratings table, so it must be an input pin. So it cannot output anything, but you seems to be saying the opposite, that it is an output pin in fact, correct? Maybe that is why I'm so confused about it.

Comment: No, I am not saying it is an output pin, that's your thinking. It is an input pin, and current will flow out of it if you try to pull it low. Just imagine the pin has internal pull-up resistor. In real life it might be a TTL logic input or something similar, or CMOS input with current source as a pull-up instead of a resistor.

Comment: @verbessern Pretty much the only way you can tell whether a pin is high or low (which is what you want from an input), is to source or sink a tiny amount of current, at least momentarily. This can be femto-amps (like in super-sensitive) but it can also be milli-amps. Devices use the flow of current into or out of a pin to detect their potential, for example by draining the charge on a MOSFET gate or the current through a BJT. Here, the IC is ready and able to send 1.6mA out of the pin and when that happens it knows the pin is connected to GND so should do its thing: that's *how* it knows.

Comment: I understand the words, but to me several things are contradicting. As an example, I cannot understand how it is safe to connect directly the pin to VCC, and why that will not oversupply the pin with more then its 5 mA of maximum current. I need some time to process it all.

Comment: Imagine you have a PCB with CMOS input with say 4k7 pull-up to VCC of 5V so the input pin is at 5V when idle. Would current flow if you pull the pin to ground? Yes. Would any current flow if you connect it to 5V? No.

Comment: Justme, this seems to have become a discussion/tutorial in comments with @verbessern. Instead, could you edit and improve your brief answer so it explains it all sufficiently, with a diagram for absolute clarity. Otherwise, future readers would have to piece together a com3 answer. Thanks.

Comment: I understand now! The CMOS's input (probably AND gate) is connected to VCC with a resistor. The enable pin is connected to the CMOS side of the resistor. By connecting it to VCC nothing changes, because there is no current flowing. By connecting to GND however the current (based on this internal resistor with an unknown value) will flow between VCC and GND as that will effectively make the CMOS to have nearly a GND voltage. If I connect in series resistor to GND that will create a voltage divider for the CMOS's input.

Comment: So...I can just connect to VCC or GND directly as both are safe to do so (just not to use too much resistance between the pin and GND). And there is this maximum of 500 Ohm @Justme said, I get that now. The internal pull-up resistor helps me, so that when I connect the enable pin to GND to limit the current flowing between VCC and GND. That is an awesome design, I like it. It saves me a resistor.

Comment: As a downside, every time I disable the IC by connecting it to GND, it will start to consume current with this internal resistor. It is a simple design for the most common case - always enabled, but forces the other use cases to "pay with current".